# Lcm of two numbers is a lot like the direct sum of two vector spaces.

Tags: category-theory, intuition

I was reading this [Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) paper and in the beginning it talks about finding connections between different parts of math. One of the examples is that how the lcm of two numbers is a lot like the direct sum of two vector spaces. I am familiar with linear algebra at the level of Axler and also real analysis. This statements sounds very intriguing. But I feel like I don’t have the background to understand the proof or the machinery of why this statement is true.

Could someone explain how this works and why is there this connection between these two concepts?

Comment: The direct sum of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is, in a sense, the "least" vector space that contains copies of both of the summands. Given any vector space $Z$ and linear maps $V\to Z$ and $W\to Z$, there is a unique linear maps $V\oplus W\to Z$ that restricts to the maps you had to begin with in the copies of $V$ and $W$.  Now consider positive integers ordered by divisibility, and instead of saying "divides" say "maps to". The lcm of $a$ and $b$ is the 'smallest' integer that both $a$ and $b$ "map to", and if both $a$ and $b$ "map to" $c$, then so does the lcm.

Comment: Terry Tao wrote [a blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2021/11/07/venn-and-euler-type-diagrams-for-vector-spaces-and-abelian-groups/) about these sorts of analogies.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, in my opinion your comment should be an answer. I would certainly upvote it

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could you please expand on your answer. I can kind of see what you’re saying. But maybe a little more explanation could help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't find the connection between direct sums and lcms convincing, to be honest. In direct sums, the original components are always preserved at a distance from each other, unlike in lcms. To me the better analogy with the lcm is the sum $W_1+W_2$ of two subspaces of the same ambient vector space.

Comment: @GregMartin The sum is the coproduct in the poset of subspaces of the ambient vector space; that category is also a poset (as is the integers with divisibility), so the analogy will seem stronger. But in the category of *all* vector spaces, the direct sum plays the equivalent role; they are all coproducts, of course.

Comment: IMHO the correct way to answer this question for yourself is to keep learning category theory. At some point you will have a good understanding of limits and colimits and will be able to see that both direct sums and the LCM are examples, and at that point it will be completely and precisely clear what they have in common. At this stage this kind of informal statement is just for motivation, and if it doesn't work for you you can just keep it in the back of your mind and come back to it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix a field $F$, and consider all vector spaces over $F$ and linear transformations between them. Given two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, the direct sum $V\oplus W$ has the following properties:

1. There exist linear transformations $i_V\colon V\to V\oplus W$ and $i_W\colon W\to V\oplus W$; (namely, $i_V(v)= (v,0_W)$, $i_W(w) = (0_V,w)$).
2. For any vector space $Z$ and linear transformations $T\colon V\to Z$ and $U\colon W\to Z$, there exists a unique linear transformation $L\colon V\oplus W\to Z$ such that $T = L\circ i_V$ and $U=L\circ i_W$. Namely, $L(v,w)=T(v)+U(w)$.
3. The direct sum is characterized up to isomorphism by properties 1 and 2: if $X$ is any vector space, and $j_V\colon V\to X$ and $j_W\colon W\to X$ are linear transformations such that for every vector space $Z$ and linear transformations $T\colon V\to Z$ and $U\colon W\to Z$ there exists a unique linear tranformation $M\colon X\to Z$ such that $T=M\circ j_V$ and $U=M\circ j_W$, then there is a unique linear isomorphism $\Phi\colon V\oplus W\to X$ such that $j_V=\Phi\circ i_V$ and $j_W=\Phi\circ i_W$.

To see 3, note that the existence of $j_V$ and $j_W$ imply the existence of a unique linear transformation $\Phi\colon V\oplus W\to X$ with $j_V=\Phi\circ i_V$ and $j_W=\Phi\circ i_W$ by 2; we need to show $\Phi$ is an isomorphism. The existence of $i_V$ and $i_W$ imply, by the properties we are assuming $X$ has, the existence of a linear transformation $\Psi\colon X\to V\oplus W$ such that $i_V=\Psi\circ j_V$ and $i_W=\Psi\circ j_W$. Then the map $\Psi\circ\Phi\colon V\oplus W\to V\oplus W$ satisfies $i_V=(\Psi\circ\Phi)\circ i_V$ and $i_W=(\Psi\circ\Phi)\circ i_W$. But so does the map $\mathrm{id}_{V\oplus W}$. The fact that in 2 we have that there is a *unique* map that satisfies this condition tells us that $\Psi\circ\Phi=\mathrm{id}_{V\oplus W}$. Now repeat the argument exchanging the roles of $X$ and $V\oplus W$ to conclude that $\Phi\circ\Psi=\mathrm{id}_X$. So $\Phi=\Psi^{-1}$ are both invertible, and we are done.

---

Consider now the nonzero integers (zero is a bit problematic, so let us leave it aside for a second). If $a$ and $b$ are integers, then the lcm of $a$ and $b$ has the following properties:

1. There exist integers $r$ and $t$ such that $ar=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ and $bt=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$.
2. For every integer $x$, if there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $am=x$ and $bn=x$, then there exists a unique integer $k$ such that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)k=x$, and $m=kr$, $n=kt$.
3. Properties 1 and 2 characterize $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ up to sign: if $M$ is an integer such that there exist integers $R$ and $T$ such that $aR=M$, $bT=M$, and for every integer $x$, if there are integers $u$ and $v$ such that $au=x$ and $bv=x$, then there exists a unique integer $K$ such that $MK=x$, and $u=KR$, $v=KT$; then $M=\pm\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$.

Property 2 is straightforward, so let me note how to show property 3 along the same lines as above for vector spaces: suppose we have $M$, $R$, and $T$ as in 3. By property 2, there exists a unique integer $k$ such that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)k=M$. But by 1, the property of $M$ in 3 tells us that there is a unique integer $K$ such that $MK=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$. Now, $M=KkM$, so $Kk=1$, which implies that $K=k=\pm 1$. Thus, $M=\pm\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$.

Now, to make the analogy clearer, imagine you have all the integers. If $a$ and $m$ are integers, then draw an arrow from $a$ to $m$ labeled with the integer $x$ if and only if $ax=m$. If $a$ does not divide $m$, then there is no arrow from $a$ to $m$.

Then property 1 above can be rewritten as:

> There is an arrow $a\stackrel{r}{\longrightarrow}\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$, and an arrow $b\stackrel{t}{\longrightarrow}\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$.

And property 2 can be rewritten as:

> If there are arrows $a\stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow}x$ and $b\stackrel{n}{\longrightarrow}x$, then there exists a unique arrow $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow}x$ such that
> $$\stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} = \stackrel{r}{\longrightarrow}\,\stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \stackrel{n}{\longrightarrow} = \stackrel{t}{\longrightarrow}\,\stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow}.$$

---

So $V\oplus W$ can be characterized, up to isomorphism, in terms of properties related to linear transformations among vector spaces related to $V$ and $W$. And $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ can be characterized, up to sign, in terms of properties related to labeled arrows among integers related to $a$ and $b$. Moreover, the characterizations of each is very similar (if not almost identical) to the other, when viewed solely in terms of existence and uniqueness of these transformations/arrows.

Thus, we can say there is an analogy between the way $V\oplus W$ behaves, relative to (i) $V$ and $W$, (ii) the linear maps $V\to V\oplus W$ and $W\to V\oplus W$, and (iii) **all** other vector spaces and linear transformations; and the way that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ behaves, realtive to (i) $a$ and $b$; (ii) the integers $r$ and $t$ such that $ar=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$, $bt=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$; and (iii) **all** other integers and divisibility/multiplication of integers. In addition, notice how similar the proofs of items 3, in terms of items 1 and 2 in the properties listed, were; that proof did not really rely on the fact that we had vector spaces and linear transformations, or integers and divisibility statements, but really on just the existence and uniqueness of certain linear transformations/arrows.

In fact, both are instances of what are called *coproducts* in their respective categories. Category Theory thrives in noticing and abstracting these kinds of similarities among sundry and diverse settings.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. What I took away from this was that the direct sum of two vector spaces and lcm of two numbers have properties, respectively, that mimic each other. If this understanding is wrong, let me know. I'll try to understand it better.

Comment: @Seeker I would say that not only do they have properties that mimic each other, but they are *characterized* by these properties, a stronger statement.